# Simplication from e to sin

Tags: trigonometry

In a lecture, I am seeing this simplification:

$$\frac{-2 \pi i}{4} \cdot (e^{\pi i/4} - e^{-\pi i/4})$$

$$= - \frac{2 \pi i }{4} \cdot 2 i \sin{\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

Why is this?

Things I know:

$e^{\pi i} = -1$ via this [proof](https://www.askamathematician.com/2009/10/q-why-is-e-to-the-i-pi-equal-to-1/)

Can someone show me how this is done?

Comment: You could use the fact that $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$

Comment: oh hello @PegasusMitchell can we be friends?

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$:
$$\frac{-2 \pi i}{4} \cdot (e^{\pi i/4} - e^{-\pi i/4})=$$
$$= \frac{-2 \pi i}{4} \cdot \biggl(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})-\cos(-\frac{\pi}{4})-i\sin(-\frac{\pi}{4})\biggr)=$$
$$=\frac{-2\pi i}{4}\biggl(i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})\biggr)=$$
$$= - \frac{2 \pi i }{4} \cdot 2 i \sin{\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

Answer (score 1):

From $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$,

$$e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x;\quad e^{-ix} = \cos x - i \sin x$$

Rearrange them to make $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ the left hand side: (a bit like solving linear equations)

$$\cos x = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2};\quad \sin x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

The result $\sin x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$ is what's being used here.